# Encrypted Home Folder, no trash functionality

Tags: trash

When I try to move a file to the trash I get:

“file.txt” can't be put in the trash. Do you want to delete it immediately?

If I try to delete it by right clicking, I get:

Are you sure you want to permanently delete “file.txt”?
If you delete an item, it will be permanently lost.

My delete key is not working. I assume it is related. I have read through the forums, and I have recreated the Trash folder under ~/.local/share/Trash, set the owner to me:me 777, and nothing. I can move files into this folder, and the files do not show up under the Trash in the sidebar. If I can right click and "Move To Trash" from this new trash folder, the file shows up in the actual Trash in the sidebar, which I can empty at that point. I'm still not able to move to Trash form anywhere else. I am not sure this related to an encrypted folder or not, but I don't have any other explanations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Xubuntu 16.04.
For all users that have an encrypted /home, the trash functionality only works for folders and files that are located inside their /home. It does not work for any folder or file located outside their /home, while it does work in any location for users whose /home is not encrypted.